# Can I add google authenticated user to users list in firebase?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app in Xamarin using firebase for the login and I would like it for users to sign up with email or google. If I sign them up via email they get added to this list of users:

[image: firebase users list]

But when I authenticate them via google then do not get added to this list. Is there a way to enable this?
I would like to later use the uid's in this list to store data per user and that is why I want them all in 1 list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user that signed in with Google, then uses their Google credentials to sign in with Firebase, their profile **does** show up in the Firebase console with a colored G icon.

For example, here's a list of some users from one of my projects:

[image]

The first user is an email+password user, then there are 3 anonymous users, and then there's a user that signed in with their Google account.

If the Google user does not show up for you, make sure you signed them in to Firebase too.

Comment: I would also like to ask a follow up question, what method or function do I use to sign them into firebase? because the only functions I see require a email and password and I do not have a password from the google authenticated users?

Comment: You're looking for `SignInWithCredentialAsync`. For such questions, I always look at the Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin and then at the Xamarin library code or samples: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/d72add8573e5b63dda71ac6b31d3dbdea8b36d67/samples/com.google.firebase/firebase-auth/FirebaseAuthQuickstart/GoogleSignInActivity.cs

Comment: alright got it to work, thanks.